# Is html input field with type file, uploading automatically or not?

Tags: php, html, file, ftp, upload

Hi I am wondering if the input field with type "file" is automatically uploading files to the server when there is a file selected by the user.

The thing I want is that a user can select files to submit it and that a PHP FTP connection is established to upload the files.

I am not sure if the browser pre-uploads the files to a temp directory on the server or does it do that only when you hit the submit button?

Because if the file is already uploaded to the server it would be unnecessary to use FTP to upload the file again only to a different location on the server.

Basically what I want to accomplish is something similar to what we transfer does. I believe they are not uploading before the user hits the button.

Can anybody point me in the right direction and provide me with some extra info about this matter. Haven't found the desired information yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is uploaded only once the form is submitted (in the same HTTP `POST` request as all other form fields). *Why don't you try it, to see yourself?*

And you cannot use PHP to upload a file via FTP from a client to a server. That's not possible. PHP runs on the server, it cannot access files on a client's machine. See also:

- [Upload a local file from application via web server with PHP code to FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52193793/850848)
- [PHP uploading file from browser to FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52794868/850848).

Comment: I did try many times, however I was always under the impression the file was pre-uploaded before it was actually processed on server level. The reason for this assumption is that it always takes a while before the file name shows up in the input field, any idea why that is?

Comment: I've never seen that. For me, it's immediate. Do you see the same delay here? https://jsfiddle.net/xdL4qt98/

Comment: Yes I see the same delay about 5 sec.

Comment: What browser? + Try turning off your antivirus.